# Setting initial value of Django ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have an Model with an m2m-Fields to an OtherModel.

```
class OtherModel(models.Model)    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

class Model(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    otherModel = models.ManyToManyField(OtherModel)
```

For the class Model I use an normal FormSet(). For the class otherModel I use a formset_factory()

I only want to allowed to select data from the database from OtherModel so I changed the CharField name in OtherModel to a ModelChoiceField with this code:

```
def otherModel_formset(self, patientenID):

    class OtherModelForm(ModelForm):
        name= ModelChoiceField(queryset=OtherModel.objects.all())

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(OtherModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        class Meta:
            model = OtherModel
            fields = ['name']

    return formset_factory(form=OtherModelForm, max_num=10)
```

I can save the selected name in the m2m Field but on the reload they selected nothing

exampel:

```
<select id=some_id" name="some_name">
     <option value="1"> HAWAII </option>
     <option value="2"> ALASKA</option> 
</select>
```

In the exampel ALASKA is selected on submit and on reload that should look in a kind of this:

```
<select id=some_id" name="some_name">
     <option value="1"> HAWAII </option>
     <option value="2" **selected="selected"**> ALASKA</option> 
</select>
```

but this stand in the html content:

```
<select id=some_id" name="some_name">
     <option value="1"> HAWAII </option>
     <option value="2"> ALASKA</option> 
</select>
```

Somebody know a solution?

Comment: You need to post relevant code: where is your view? Your view needs to send the bound form (form(request.POST) back to the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is use `request.POST` and `initial={'name': 'ALASKA'}` together. This happens because the values of `request.POST` always override the values of parameter "initial", so we have to put it separated. My solution was to use this way.

In `views.py`:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form=OtherModelForm(request.POST) 
else:
    form=OtherModelForm()
```

In `forms.py`:

```
class OtherModelForm(ModelForm):
    name= ModelChoiceField(queryset=OtherModel.objects.all(), initial={'name': 'ALASKA'})
```

---------- or ----------

In `views.py`:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form=OtherModelForm(request.POST) 
else:
    form=OtherModelForm(initial={'name': 'ALASKA'})
```

In `forms.py`:

```
class OtherModelForm(ModelForm):
    name= ModelChoiceField(queryset=OtherModel.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have something in your view that looks something along the lines of:

```
form=OtherModelForm(request.POST, initial={'name': 'ALASKA'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the follow code:

```
otherModel = OtherModel.objects.all()
otherModelFormSet = otherModel_formset(id)
otherModelList = otherModel.values('id', 'name')
inProgressOtherModel = otherModelFormSet(None, initial=otherModelList, prefix='otherModel')
```